# execvp causing memory problems

Tags: c, linux

In my C program I am using the execvp command to parse an input and run it.
I have this:

```
char read_str[MAX_ALLOWED_BUFFER];
pid_t child_pid;
char *strs[100] = {NULL}; 

child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == 0) {
    split(read_str, strs);
    execvp(strs[0], strs);
    printf("Failed\n");
}
else {
    waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
    for (y = 0; y < 100; y++) free(strs[y]);
}
```

and this function

```
void split(char *str, char **splitstr) {      
    char *p;      
    int i=0;      
    p = strtok(str," "); 
    while(p!= NULL) {        
        splitstr[i] = malloc(strlen(p) + 1);
        if (splitstr[i]) strcpy(splitstr[i], p);
        i++;
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");       
    } 
}
```

the first code block is in a while loop and keeps asking user input. Anyways, if execvp returns, then an error occured and it prints failed, then if I type two more valid commands, i get a memory corruption error...

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: *"I am using the execvp command to parse an input and run it."* Using unfiltered user input this way is an unbelieably bad idea. What if I send your program `rm -rf ~/` or pass Little Bobby Tables' name to your big production database?

Comment: Assuming the program being built is a shell, which appears to be the case: A shell is supposed to do that. It's kind of the point. Don't assume a security issue here unless there's some larger context which suggests that input from an **untrusted** user is involved.

Answer (score 0):

> what I am doing wrong here

A couple of things.

- when `execvp` fails, the child goes to the beginning of the while loop, and now you have *both* the child and the parent reading input. What you want to do is `exit(1)` after printing `"Failed"`.
- if you did that, then the `strs` is never allocated in the parent, and doesn't need to be `free()`d. You could move the definition of `strs` into the `if (child_pid == 0) {`, and you never need to worry about `free`ing anything.

This doesn't explain your memory corruption problem, which goes like this:

- failed `execvp` leaves child `C1` reading the input. `C1` has `malloc()`ed entries in its `strs` array.
- now `C1` gets the input, `fork()`s `C2` and `waitpid`s for it. Then `C1` calls `free` on `strs` entries, and they become dangling (you should `NULL` them out).
- now `C1` gets the input again, `fork`s `C3`, `waitpid`s for it, and calls `free` on the *same* `strs` entries again, resulting in double-`free` and corruption that you have observed.